# refresh listview created from an arraylist after delete operation

Tags: android, listview, refresh, adapter

I have seen too many questions about refreshin a listview and I have tried every solution on the topics but none worked for me.

have tried `notifysetdatachange()`, `invalidateviews`, `refreshdrawablestate()` but none worked.

I have an `arraylist` and after an `longclick` operation I am deleting an item from arraylist.and I want it to disappear from listview.but it does not.

but after deletion if I open another activity and turn back to the activity which contains my `listview` it disappears.

so my deletion operation is successful, I just want to know how to refresh listview.,

I did not post a code because there is nothing unique I am just using

I have an `arraylist` named `al_6`.I am filling it with objects.

then I send them to the my `adapter` like

```
adapter = new ContentSearchListAdapter(getActivity(), channels2,
                options);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and when I want to delete an object from my arraylist.

```
al_6.remove(position)
```

and as I said before the deletion operation is successful

Comment: you have to add some more code to get answer. single line of code that too remove item from arraylist is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should use these syntax for achieving it

```
((YourAdaptor)Listview.getAdaptor()).notifyDataSetChange();
```

Comment: Questionnaire already said that he used notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: but its not specigy how to use it he is applying dotifydatasetchange without getting adaptor...

Comment: I have used it as you said ((ContentSearchListAdapter) mylistview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); but still no change at all.

Comment: did it as you said but still nothing

Comment: you should add your code in the question so we can get more clarification.

Comment: I have marked this as solution.but before using the code line you posted I did adapter.remove(adapterobject.get(position)) .after that the object in the listview dynamically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and for your adapter class,

```
   // query fire on your deletion operation
   mArrayList.remove(position);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: as i said in the first place I have tried that, and it does not work

Comment: sorry did not understand what you asked?

Comment: I say u, for which adpater class used baseAdapter class used?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is strange the behaviour of the listview to refresh it. I always do the same to refresh listView without problems:

- Use custom Adapter which extends from **BaseAdapter**
- Use **ArrayList<>** structure data into the adapter. If you have your data in a database SQLiteDatabase, I recomend to put the data you need int that list in an ArrayList and pass it to the adapter. I can't do the same with CursorAdapter :(
- Make your ArrayList and your Adapter **public static** in your Activity if you plan to modify the data outside the Activity and want to update the list.
- When you modify or remove any info from your data (if you do it directly on your database, duplicate the same into the ArrayList), use the public static reference of the Adapter of your Activity to call his method **notifyDataSetChanged()**