# Refresh ListView from ActionMode.Callback.onDestroyActionMode()

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-actionmode

This is a question that has been floating around on StackOverflow for a little while, and before you mark this question as a duplicate I am aware of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099299/refresh-listview-created-from-an-arraylist-after-delete-operation). However, this question is vague, has no code, and doesn't seem to have been fully answered.

So on to my question:

I have a `ListFragment` (MainListFragment) that, `onLongItemClick`, opens up a `Contextual Action Bar`. One of the menu items within this Contextual Action Bar enables the deletion of the `ListView` item that was long-clicked.

Within the class that implements `ActionMode.Callback`, I am able to delete the long-clicked item, but I need the `ListView` to refresh itself after this deletion so users don't have to switch Fragments to see the effects of the deletion.

Here you can see my `onLongItemClickListener` within `MainListFragment`:

```
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "made it to the listener");
            MainListContextualMenu menu = new MainListContextualMenu();
            //view.startActionMode(menu);
            ActionMode mode = getActivity().startActionMode(menu);
            Object[] tags = new Object[2];
            tags[0] = view.getRootView().getContext();
            tags[1] = pos;
            mode.setTag(tags);
            //view.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

And here is my ActionMode.Callback-implementing class:

```
public class MainListContextualMenu implements ActionMode.Callback{

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.main_list_contextual_menu_delete:

        //MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) mode.getCustomView().getContext();
        //activity.getLists().remove(mode.getTag());

        Object[] tags = (Object[]) mode.getTag();
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) tags[0];
        int index = (Integer) tags[1];
        //Log.d("My Debug Bitches","" +index);
        //Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "size before " + activity.getLists().size());
        activity.getLists().remove(index);
        //Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "size after " + activity.getLists().size());
        break;
    case R.id.main_list_contextual_menu_edit:
        break;
    }


    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_list_contextual_menu, menu);
    Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "menu inflated");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Object[] tags = (Object[]) mode.getTag();
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) tags[0];
    ListView view = (ListView) activity.getCurrentFocus();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

I have tried using `invalidateViews()` within my `onDestroyActionMode()` method to no avail, and I have seen others recommend `notifyDataSetChange()`.

However, I am not sure how to use these solutions within an ActionMode.Callback. If you look at my `onLongClick()` method, I use `mode.setTag()` to pass both the `MainActivity` and the `position` of the ListView item that was clicked. Is this good form?

I just want to be able to refresh the `ListView` from `MainListFragment` within the `ActionMode.Callback.onDestroyActionMode()` method.

Has anyone gotten this to work before, and if so, does he/she have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting this answer according to your implementation,there may be a better way, first create a method `getAdapter()`  which will return your `adapter` which you are using for your `listview`.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter;

public ArrayAdapter getAdapter()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return adapter;
    }
```

Now change your code like this this, add this   `activity.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
case R.id.main_list_contextual_menu_delete:

        //MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) mode.getCustomView().getContext();
        //activity.getLists().remove(mode.getTag());

        Object[] tags = (Object[]) mode.getTag();
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) tags[0];
        int index = (Integer) tags[1];
        //Log.d("My Debug Bitches","" +index);
        //Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "size before " + activity.getLists().size());
        activity.getLists().remove(index);
        activity.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "size after " + activity.getLists().size());
        break;
```

Hope it will help.